# Linux cron job fails to execute part of script which works in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, batch-file, cron

I'm having a problem with a script that writes to a log file during a backup procedure. Tested perfectly when called from the root shell, but fails when run from the cron demon.

Backup is done over a series of partitions and the on-site admin will rotate the drives in the top dock weekly. In order to know where the most recent backup is located I've included the following lines

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb | grep 'Model Number'
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb | grep 'Serial Number'
```

I've tried this with a `>> /batch/backup.log` and without.
When the bash script is run from the command line, it works beautifully. But when the crontab calls the script the output from these lines is blank.

crontab entry: `00 00 * * * /batch/backup.bat >> /batch/backup.log`

I have no idea why other than the possibility that cron can't handle the pipe or the grep or something.

I have isolated the lines in a test.bat but they remain blank.

The backup script uses the hdparm to spin down the drive at the end, but now I wonder if that's not working properly either if cron can't handle hdparm.

Comment: Tried the hdparm line as its own cronjob, cut and paste from the script, and it worked as its own job, it just doesn't work if it is in the script and called by the cron daemon. Is this a cron /bin/bash disconnect?

Comment: sudo might be trying to ask for a password. You don't need sudo in a cron job run by root.

Comment: As what user do you run the cron job? Can you do _any_ `sudo` commands?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/173924/how-to-run-a-cron-job-using-the-sudo-command

Comment: If these commands work in isolation then they are not the problem. Missing close quote somewhere earlier in your script?

Comment: `grep -E '(Model|Serial) Number'`

Comment: The problem seems to have been that, although cron could run the hdparm command exactly as I wanted, it was unable to find the command when it opened the bash shell. Adding /sbin/ to hdparm fixed the problem. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is probably because `hdparm` is not in the PATH when the script is executed through cron. Although less likely, same might apply to `grep` as well.

Try replacing `hdparm` with `/full/path/to/hdparm` in your script.

Comment: Perfect. I added /sbin/hdparm and am now getting the proper output, and feel better about the staff removing the drive in the morning after the backup.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either put this in the `root` crontab, or you need to store your password in plain text and pipe it into the `sudo` command.  That second option is obviously NOT RECOMMENDED. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/173924/how-to-run-a-cron-job-using-the-sudo-command

As @Paul hinted, it is also possible to create a directive in `/etc/sudoers` to override the need for a password for a specific user / host / command combination.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/159009

Copying just a little bit from that answer:

If your user is called `user` and your host is called `host` you could add these lines to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
user host = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown 
user host = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
```

This will allow the user user to run the desired commands on host without entering a password. All other sudoed commands will still require a password.

Comment: One can also set up sudo to allow the particular commands needed by that user without a password.  I don't recall the exact format but it should be in `man sudo`

Comment: @Paul thanks - I have updated my answer with the how-to (and a link).

Comment: :-) He wants to run hdparm (and who knows what else, without the script)

Comment: This is the root cron. I'm running `crontab -e` from the root terminal to call the script.

Comment: I ran hdparm without the script to see if cron was able to do so. It needs to be in the script to control the output to the log file. It was purely a troubleshooting attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the crontab entry as below

00 00 * * * /batch/backup.bat 1> /batch/backup.op 2> /batch/backup.err

Standard output will be redirected to /batch/backup.op
Standard error will be redirected to /batch/backup.err

Check the errors in /batch/backup.err and fix

Comment: Thanks for this. The fact that I got NO errors helped me to figure out what was going on. the 2> will be terribly useful later on as well.